# How to add comment to an existing table in Rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, phppgadmin

I am working with a ROR project, and I want to add comments to each tables. I can do this directly by altering the tables in phppgadmin, but I want to do this using **migrations**. I have searched a lot but no luck.

I tried to do the same in the following way:

```
def change
    set_table_comment :active_admin_comments, 'This table stores stuff.'
  end
```

But again no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `migration_comments` for adding comments in migration files. For more details visit [migration_comments](https://github.com/pinnymz/migration_comments).

Comment: No reason to use a gem for this anymore, as it's native to Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 5 you can do this natively with [change_table_comment](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table_comment)

```
def change
  change_table_comment :active_admin_comments, 'This table stores stuff.'
end
```